# Finding a layer in Visual Laser Marker

Tags: vba, object, find, layer

I have a problem with execution. When I try to execute I got message that there is missing a reference in VLM.

The error is:969xxxxxx.vlm:Object'Group1234', ID = 123 reference missing QP-set'Layer'

I got this many errors before with many more object and ID names. I managed to change a lot of that mistakes by changing the layer of those object but there is still some object that need a layer changing. My question is how to find that specific object in VLM. Is there any function in VLM where I can find specific object by typing its name (or even through ID name)?

I tried to press ctrl+F. I looked into layer options. Didn't manage to find it.